# css3 Chrome width % bad calculation rounding

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, rounding-error

Hi i'm trying to display a 5 column layout but the fifth column displays under.

```
.five-col{
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

I inspect the layout and is 1903px width (100%). And each .five-col is 381px so 381*5=1905px Is it a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing any issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4uwckjzh/

HTML:

```
<div class="five-col"></div>
<div class="five-col"></div>
<div class="five-col"></div>
<div class="five-col"></div>
<div class="five-col"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.five-col{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.five-col{
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Maybe it's because of a box-sizing missing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work for me. It depends of your screen resolution. Google Chrome not work with sub-pixels. So when it round the result overlap the layout and the fifth element goes down.

Comment: I have no issue when horizontally resizing the window in my jsfiddle.

Comment: Here, now they have a parent div with a 1903px width: http://jsfiddle.net/4uwckjzh/1/

Comment: I'm pretty convinced you just forgot to set the box-sizing to border-box.

Comment: I add box-sizing: border-box; and I still having the isue :( I try your example and works, but in my code doesn't

Comment: Create a jsfiddle where we can see the issue please. We'll start from there.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/ Here is somebody with the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72006/discussion-between-pablo-levin-and-jlowcs).